# Почему в лямбда-выражении у переменной не то значение, которое я ей присвоил?

Tags: c#, unity3d, замыкания, лямбда-выражение

```cs
ToolsList = ToolsGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < ToolsList.Count; i++)
{
    ToolsList[i].onValueChanged.AddListener(on =>
    {
        if (on)
        {
            toolId = i;
        }
    });
}
```

Сверху часть моего кода, в котором переменная `i` соответственно `toolId` получает невозможное значение. Почему невозможное? Потому что список `ToolList` от создания вселенной до самого конца имеет 4 объекты в нём.

[image]

И поскольку `i` всегда меньше `ToolsList.Count`, он никак не может быть 4. Но он как то умудряется стать 4 и более того, он всегда 4.

---

*Как это происходит?*
*Как это исправить?*

Comment: Интересный вопрос на самом деле, я предполагаю что замыкание пытается взять значение из переменной i после того как цикл отработал, а не запомнить копию и ей пользоваться. Посмотрю у себя в отладчике. И да, почему код картинкой?

Comment: @trollingchar теперь без картинок)

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский `toolId` только для чтения. Единственное место это тут.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Типичная проблема с захватом переменной. К моменту вызова вашего события цикл уже закончился и переменная i уже равна ToolsList.Count. Чтобы избежать этой прблемы, можно сначала скопировать её в локальную переменную внутри цикла, и уже локальную захватывать

```
ToolsList = ToolsGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < ToolsList.Count; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    ToolsList[i].onValueChanged.AddListener(on =>
    {
        if (on)
        {
            toolId = j;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело в лямбде

```
(on =>
{
    if (on)
    { toolId = i; }
})
```

Вы используете `i` из цикла. Поскольку код в лямбде выполняется не сразу, а в какой-то другой момент времени после цикла, `i` действительно равно 4 (т.к. инкрементируется в цикле)

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже помог и я бы сделал его решением вопроса но Stack Overflow разрешает только на 1 решение. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Во-первых, tym32167 меня опередил где-то на 1 минуту. А во-вторых, он не только объяснил причину, но и показал способ ее устранения. Так что все правильно - его ответ "вернее" моего.

Answer (score -1):

у вас в инспекторе указано что ToolID = 4. Вот он и выходит за границы

Comment: В начале он 0 он в `Start`-е он становится 4

Comment: Если хотите я могу гиф аоказать

Comment: покажите лучше что в старте происходит

Comment: в старте я ни разу не использовал toolId поэтому не хотел показать но если хотите https://pastebin.com/Hr1RjBLz