# Есть класс Singleton Builder, как ограничить количество инициализированных элементов

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

Дан класс Singleton.cs, который из шаблона класса T создаст Singleton-экземпляр этого класса:

```cs
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static Lazy<T> instance_ = new Lazy<T>();

    protected Singleton() { }

    private static Lazy<T> CreateInstance()
    {
        System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo cInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new Type[0],
            new System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[0]);
        return (Lazy<T>)cInfo.Invoke(null);
    }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance_ == null)
                instance_ = CreateInstance();
            return instance_.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Нужно модифицировать класс Singleton** таким образом, чтобы можно было создать и управлять фиксированным числом объектов.

Если, например, изменить сущность этого класса на массив сущностей и добавить счётчик, т.е.:

```cs
private static Lazy<T>[] instance_ = new Lazy<T>[10];
private static int i = -1;
```

то при использовании обновленного инициализатора:

```cs
public static T Instance
{
    get
    {
        i++;
        if (instance_[i] == null)
            instance_[i] = CreateInstance();
        return instance_[i].Value;
     }
}
```

получим Null Reference Exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object. **cInfo was null**.)

Понятное дело, что инициализатор должен быть переделан, но даже в таком виде он не работает.

Так же возникает вопрос каким образом отслеживать количество актуальных экземпляров классов, т.к. нужно чтобы с помощью класса Singleton.cs в WinForms-приложении можно было создать не более **n** окон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eсли смотреть самый простой вариант, то вот так

```
public static class FormsSingletone
{
    private static Form[] _instances = new Form[10];

    public static void ShowForm()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _instances.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            if (_instances[j] == null)
            {
                var f = new Form();
                _instances[j] = f;

                FormClosedEventHandler handler = null;
                handler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    f.FormClosed -= handler;                    
                    _instances[j] = null;
                };

                f.FormClosed += handler;
                f.Show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хоть и решение было обобщенным до форм, думаю, оно сгодится, разве что не понимаю строки int j = i, почему бы просто не обращаться по индексу i? Так же для моего решения я добавил break после f.Show(), чтобы за одно использование метода создалась только 1 форма.

Comment: @Nether `добавил break` - правильно сделали. `не понимаю строки int j = i`, чтобы избежать захвата счетчика (примеры [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009090/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011408/179763)), но имея break это уже не особо нужно.

Comment: @tym32167 объясните незнаящему чем принципиально отличается для замыкания локальная переменная на уровне метода, на уровне цикла или на уровне тела цикла...ведь все это локальная переменная. Ведь если я ничего не путаю все эти замыкания лишь сахар, в IL это все равно представляется как имплантация интерфейса с конструктором, куда скидываются все локальные переменные в пределе метода. Или я уже отстал от прогресса и власть поменялась. Спрашиваю потому что на самом деле удивлен.

Comment: @skingreek мы же не сайте вопросов и ответов, если у вас есть вопрос, задайте его как вопрос, а не как комментарий.