# Запись происходит не в ту строку listbox в которую должна записаться

Tags: c#, winforms

**UPD:** Пока не справился - проблема осталась

По какой причине в многопоточном режиме может происходить запись не в ту строку listbox ?

Вот так запускаю выполнение одного и того же алгоритма разных потоках

```
    var algoritmRaboti0 = new Thread(() => Algoritm(0, 3));
    algoritmRaboti0.Start();

    var algoritmRaboti1 = new Thread(() => Algoritm(1, 3));
    algoritmRaboti1.Start();

    var algoritmRaboti1 = new Thread(() => Algoritm(2, 3));
    algoritmRaboti1.Start();
```

Вот так из алгоритма заполняю строки в listBox

```
    private void Algoritm(int num1, int num2)
    {
        ...
        for (int i = num1; i < length; i += num2)
        {
           int j = i;
           string nomer;
           ...
           listBoxNomer.BeginInvoke(new Delegate(ListBoxNomerChange), j, nomer);
           ...
        }
        ...
    }


        public delegate void Delegate(int num,string text);
        public void ListBoxNomerChange(int num, string text)
        {
            listBoxNomer.Items.Insert(num, text);
        }
```

Воспроизвести не получается и найти почему, тоже, но я отслеживаю значение `i` и вижу что оно равно допустим 4, а данные записываются в 6 строку `listBox`, хотя должны записаться в 5 строку.

Почему такое может происходить ?

Comment: вы это в цикле поди запускаете? `listBoxNomer.BeginInvoke(new Delegate(ListBoxNomerChange), i, nomer);`

Comment: @tym32167 да - всё верно

Comment: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011408/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009090/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 воу - оперативно! Спасибо вам - понял что происходит!

Comment: пожалкуйста, на здоровье

Comment: @tym32167 внутри цикла создал локальную переменную j - записываю в неё номер итерации цикла, но всё равно записи идут не в те строки listBox туда переодически(

Comment: не очень понятно, что у вас не работает. Вы создаете 2 параллельных потока, в каждом потоке вы запускаете цикл. То есть у вас работают 2 параллельных цикла и потому записи могут идти не по порядку.

Comment: @tym32167 Всё верно, создаю 2 параллельных потока и в каждом потоке запускаю один и тот же цикл, но с разным шагом. Внутри цикла отправляются данные в listBox, и например должна заполниться 4я строка, а заполняется 5я почему то. Даже переписывая значение шага цикла i в локальную переменную j. Т.е. j = 3 например, а запись через делегат идёт в 5 строку.

Comment: у вас 3 параллельных цикла, они идут по каждому значению от 0 до `length`. Например, 5я строка заполнится  на втором шаге вот этого вызова `Algoritm(2, 3)`

Comment: @tym32167 вот и я на это рассчитываю(, а происходят странности. записывается в другие места(

Comment: вы что то путаете, `listBoxNomer.Items.Insert(num, text);` как думете, куда это будет записывать, если пробовать все время вставлять в позиции 3, 2, 1? Останется ли элемент, который был на позиции 3, на той же позиции 3?

Comment: @tym32167 Наверно не так понял работу listBox. я хотел его использовать как статичную таблицу и если я записал значение под индексом 3 то оно там должно быть и остаться. А цикл должен прыгать и записывать в одном потоке в 0,3,9..., в другом 1,4,7... , в третьем 2,5,8...

Comment: вы думаете, что вот это - `listBoxNomer.Items` - массив, но он не массив.

Comment: @tym32167 разобрался в его работе, поигравшись с ним отдельно, ещё раз спасибо! Двух зайцев помогли убить xD И про проскоки в цикле узнал и про listBox подробнее.

Comment: пожалкуйста, на здоровье