# Многопоточное считывание файла c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

возникла потребность в нескольких потоках читать и обрабатывать файл.
Есть массив потоков, каждый из них считывает свою область файла.
Ниже код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < proccesorsCount; i++)
{
     start = end * i;
     _end = end * (i + 1);
     threads[i] = new Thread(() => _readFile(fileName, start, _end));
     threads[i].Name = "Поток №" + i;
     threads[i].Start();
     Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Собственно, вопрос: Если убрать Thread.Sleep(10), то с индексами start и _end, начинают твориться чудеса. Например, они становятся равны индексам последнего блока во всех потоках:

---

[image: магия индексов]

Примечание: Я знаю, что можно использовать ThreadPool и т.п., но мне интересно, что здесь происходит

Comment: Типичная проблема с захватом переменных

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/179763, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011408/179763, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009090/179763

Comment: Но я пробовал заранее, рассчитывать значения границ и заносить их в массив, и передавать i-значение массива и тот же результат

Comment: Пока писал догадался, что цикл уже проходит и он передает ```i = processorCount```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.